# Issue with a simple Objective-C Program in Xcode [mac]

Tags: xcode, macos

I obviously imported `Foundation` first. I then created the variables in the interface and defined them in the implementation, and finally the main program is where the task is supposed to be performed and print the age and weight.

I haven't open or drained a pool because I read that the method of allocating memory has changed from `NSAutoreleasepool` to `@Autoreleasepool` or something like that, but I'm not sure if it's necessary on new Xcode versions or how to implement it into my program if it is needed.

I'm not sure why when I run the code it doesn't display my age and weight. I know the object is being created but I'm not sure where the issue is because Xcode isn't throwing any errors and the code looks clean to me.

```
//  Created by Andrew on 7/24/15.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person: NSObject {
     int age;
     int weight;
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setAge: (int) a;
-(void) setWeight: (int) w;
@end

@implementation Person

-(void) print{
     NSLog(@"I am %i years old and I weigh %i pounds", age, weight);
}
-(void) setAge: (int)a {
     age=a;
}
-(void) setWeight: (int)w {
     weight=w;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argV[]) {

    Person *andrew = [[Person alloc]init];

     [andrew setAge: 16];
     [andrew setWeight: 135];
     [andrew print];

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your code runs fine, without errors — good job. `NSLog` sends any output to the console, so maybe you weren't aware of that. I'm not sure how you're executing the code, but if you want output in terminal perhaps try `printf("I am %i years old and I weigh %i pounds", age, weight);` instead.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks for clarifying. Yeah I wasn't aware of the output being sent to the console. I am executing the code inside XCode in a project, but I will test it out with terminal. Thanks again!

Comment: In Xcode you can bring up the console by using `Shift + Command + C` before you run your code. The same output would also be in `Console.app`